# Does a SIM only cell phone contract help credit rating?

Tags: united-states, credit-score, contracts, mobile-phone-plans

I have been told that cell phone contracts are sometimes a way to improve one's credit score.

This makes sense to me as a phone contract involves a commitment to pay monies at a regular interval, much like a loan, which contracts including a phone at a discounted up front rate effectively are.

However it is unclear to me (even after some Googling) if this extends to SIM only contracts. There is still a financial commitment however no loan as such.

My my question is this, is there any potential positive effect to one's credit score to take out a SIM only phone contract in the United States?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never seen any of my mobile phone providers report any data to any credit agency. They tend to only do that if you **don't** pay on time.

Maybe sometimes it helps, but from my experience over the last decade - it must be some very rare times.

Comment: I thought this might be the case, I will wait a while in case there are other answers with additional info, otherwise shall accept this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there are nuances between countries and appreciate your question is specifically about the US, but in the UK, mobile phone contracts, including SIM only, as seen by the chat in [this experion website chat](http://www.experian.co.uk/blogs/consumer-advice/missed-late-payments/) shows that mobile contracts are included in credit ratings for 6 years.